# How to anaesthetise mosquitoes during a mass-trapping field study?

Tags: entomology, methods

Do any of you have experience in anaesthetising mosquitoes during a mass-trapping field study?

Normally, mosquito traps have a little net in which you catch the mosquitoes. The nets can, after collection, be placed in a freezer to knock out the mosquitoes. However, the trap used for my study doesn't have a net, so mosquitoes will fly around inside the trap.

I thought about using Ethyl Acetate to knock out the mosquitoes, however, the trap needs to stay clean of odours, so that's not an option. I think using CO2 would be most convenient, but I will not be able to drag a big CO2 cylinder to all my trapping locations.

Is it maybe possible to use CO2 tablets which can be dissolved in water? I could then use a plastic bottle where the cap is connected to a tube, which I can place in the trap. Would this be efficient? What do you think?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What type of trap are you using?

Comment: It's a new prototype from Biogents. Not sure if I'm allowed to give more information on that. I've already started the study and used a big freezer back at the lab where the trap fits as a whole, but that's not very convenient since the traps need to be placed back in the field on the same day.